# Get the last item registered, in a one-to-many relationship, in scope search

Tags: laravel, eloquent, relationship

I have this in Process model

```
public function tracing()
{
    return $this->hasMany(Tracing::class, 'process_id');
} 

public function lasttracing()
{
   return $this->hasOne(Tracing::class);
}
```

I have this in Tracing model

```
public function process()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(Process::class);
}
```

Finally in Process model I have scopesearch function:

```php
public function scopesearch($query, $mode, $area_id)
{
    return $query->when($mode, function ($q) use ($mode) {
        $user = session()->get('personal');
        $area_id = $user['area_id'];
        switch ($mode) {
            case 'entrada':  
                $q->whereHas('tracing', function ($q2) use ($area_id) {
                    return $q2->latest()->where('area_id', $area_id)                                
                              ->whereIn('accion', ['SEND', 'TO REGISTER']);
                    // return $q2->where('area_id', $area_id)->whereNull('recieved');
                })->whereIn('situation', ['REGISTERED', 'SENT']);
                break;
            case 'bandeja':
                break;
            case 'salida':
                break;
            case 'general':
                break;
            case 'archivos':
                break;
            case 'courier':
                break;
        }
    })->orderby('number', 'asc');
}
```

My probem is that I need to obtain the last tracing, of each process within the scopesearch function, and from there filter it according to the cases.

EDITED
I get the last tracing of this area, I need to get the last tracing in general, and after that check if it belongs to that area (area_id) that I need or no. I have already tried to use the lasttracing function but without results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two ways to limit a relationship's results:

1. If you're querying the relationship of a single model (a single Process in your case), you can use the `limit()` method inside a Closure inside the `with()` method.

```php
Process::query()
    ->where('id', $id) // querying a single Process
    ->search(...)
    ->with(['tracing' => fn($tracing) => $tracing->limit(1)])
    ->get();
```

2. If you're querying the relationship of more than a single model (multiple Processes in your case), you will need to use the `setRelation()` method inside a Closure inside the `map()` method **after** returning the Collection. This won't prevent Eloquent from querying the entire relationship. It just filters the result at the end.

```php
Process::query()
    ->search(...)
    ->with(['tracing'])
    ->get()
    ->map(fn($process) => $process->setRelation('tracing', $process->tracing->take(1));
```

or

```php
Process::query()
    ->search(...)
    ->with(['tracing'])
    ->get()
    ->map(fn($process) => $process->setRelation('tracing', $process->tracing->first());
```

depending on your use case.